# call function in underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, underscore.js

I want use one function in my template underscore. my function created in my .javascript file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function en2per(str){
      str = typeof(str) == "number" ? str.toString() : str;
      var output = '';
      var num = 1728;
      for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(str.charCodeAt(i)>=48 && str.charCodeAt(i)<=57)
          output += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+num);
        else
          output += str[i];
        }
    return output;
    };

    var order_temp = _.template($("#order_template").html());
    var order_json = {orders:data.orders};
    $('#full .pages').append(order_temp(order_json));
</script>
```

and this is my templete underscore :

```
<script type="text/template" id="order_template">
   <ul class="item_list">
   <% _.each(orders,function(item){%>
     <li class="cells">
       <div class="part number">
          <span class="spans"><%= en2per(item.counter)%></%> // I get error this place...
       </div>
     </li>
   <% });%>
   </ul>
</script>
```

when run my code I got error ... in my template underscore this function **en2per()** not found!!!
Now I want call this function in my template.

Comment: **What** error do you get???

Comment: @Bergi Uncaught ReferenceError: en2per is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your execution is:

1) The `en2per` function and the underscore template need to be declared (any order should work)

2) The jQuery needs to use the template

3) The underscore template needs to use the `en2per` function

This is all solved by making sure the `en2per` function is not in a `$(document).ready()` handler, and making sure the jQuery using the template (so the template will need to have been loaded) is:

```
<script type="text/template" id="order_template">
    ....
</script>

<script>
    function en2per(str) {
        ....
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var order_temp = _.template($("#order_template").html());
        var order_json = {orders:data.orders};
        $('#full .pages').append(order_temp(order_json));
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/L3oLsvq8/)